# How to prove this statement about matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\left(a_{i j}\right)$ be a nonzero real $n \times n$ matrix such that $a_{i j}=0$ for $i \geq j$. If $\sum_{i=0}^{k} c_{i} A^{i}=0$  for some $c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$, then prove that $c_{0}=c_{1}=0$. Here $A^{i}$ is the i -th power of A.

I've tried like this:
Let $A=\left(a_{i j}\right)$ be a nonzero real $n \times n$ matrix such that $a_{i j}=0$
Then all the terms below the diagonal including principal diagonal is Zero

Therefore, A is strictly triangular matrix.
Any strictly triangular matrix must be nilpotent i.e.A is nilpotent which implies $A^k=0$ for some $k \in\mathbb{N}$.
A satisfies the polynomial $x^k=0$

How to proceed to next step?

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts?  Simple problem-statement questions are frowned upon here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Suppose $(a_{ij})_t$ denotes the $ij^{th}$ element of $A^t$, then $(a_{11})_s= 0 = (a_{12})_t$, for all $s\geq 1$ and for all $t\geq 2$. Can you see why?

Now, from your equation, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}A^i=0$, equating term-wise sums of matrices, we have
$$c_0(a_{11})_0+c_1(a_{11})_1+\dots +c_k(a_{11})_k=0.$$
By the previous paragraph amd noticing thaf $(a_{11})_0=1$, we end up in $c_0=0$. Similarly
$$c_0(a_{12})_0+c_1(a_{12})+\dots +c_k(a_{12})_k =0.$$
From the Hint and also noticing that $(a_{12})_0=0$, we end up in $c_1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the smallest $k$ such that $A^k=0$, it must be larger than $1$. However if $c_0$ or $c_1\neq0$ $k$ can be smaller. Actually $c_0=\cdots=c_{k-1}=0$.